# Google Maps - Disable element if Google cannot determine Address Location

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the following scripting to load homes for sale on to my Google Map. I like to know if this is possible and if it is -- I need help from a really good Google Map programmer to help add it.

**What I Am Look For**
If one of the addresses within the left panel cannot be found by Google or is out of boundaries, it still loads the element and address to the left panel -- but in a disabled state by adding a class to that element. Can this be done?

**Mapping Boundaries**
Here is the boundaries, if the marker is within this area it adds the marker else disables the element. If the with boundaries cannot be done, I will take the option of Google not finding it.
http://www.freemaptools.com/radius-around-point.htm?clat=44.512176171071054&clng=-81.08184814453125&r=96.39586143951128&lc=FFFFFF&lw=1&fc=00FF00

**Scripting I Am Using**
http://www.raymondcamden.com/demos/2012/dec/1/new4.html

**Here Is What I Have So Far**
I put together the follow scripting based on the site above, just looking to add the missing location element to this concept.

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var lastinfowindow;
var locIndex;
if (!Array.prototype.forEach) {
    Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
        for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
            fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
        }
    }
}
var data = [
    {address:'123 GODERICH ST GODERICH ONTARIO',title:'123 GODERICH ST'},
    {address:'123 KNOWLES LANE KINCARDINE ONTARIO',title:'123 KNOWLES LANE'}
];
function Initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(44.00, -80.00);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom : 8,
        center : latlng,
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        scaleControl : true,
        mapTypeControl : false,
        navigationControlOptions : {
            style : google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        },
        scrollwheel : false,
        minZoom : 7,
        maxZoom : 15,
        keyboardShortcuts : false,
        disableDoubleClickZoom : true,
        draggable : true,
        backgroundColor : '#FFFFFF'
    };
    var mapStyles = [{
        featureType: 'poi',
        stylers: [{
            visibility: 'off'
        }]
    }];
    var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyles, {name: 'Styled Map'});
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    map.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
    map.setMapTypeId('map_style');
    icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/pointer.png', new google.maps.Size(19, 29), new google.maps.Point(0, 0), new google.maps.Point(8, 29));
    data.forEach(function(mapData,idx) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address':mapData.address}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    title: mapData.title,
                    icon: icon
                });
                var contentHtml = "<div style='width:300px;height:200px'><h3>"+mapData.title+"</h3>"+mapData.address+"</div>";
                var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: contentHtml
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map,marker);
                });
                marker.locid = idx+1;
                marker.infowindow = infowindow;
                markers[markers.length] = marker;
                var sideHtml = '<p class="loc" data-locid="'+marker.locid+'"><b>'+mapData.title+'</b><br/>';
                     sideHtml += mapData.address + '</p>';
                     $('#locations').append(sideHtml); 
            }
        });
    });
}
window.onload = Initialize;
```

I am currently in the process of seeing if I can do this and will update along the way. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the status of the geocode call is either

```
ZERO_RESULTS
INVALID_REQUEST
```

or one of the other [status codes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#GeocoderStatus) in the Maps API, such as

```
geocoder.geocode({'address':mapData.address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
       //handle valid address search
    } else if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.INVALID_REQUEST 
                  || status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {
       //handle no results returned
    }
}
```

If you have a geocode request return one of those statuses, you can add the element to the map, but set the marker to a reduced visibility state or some other option that you prefer.  For something like this, look into the MarkerOptions and associated Marker documentation at the link above.

Comment: Beautiful, I will try this out Jason and see what happens.